# MySQL Запрос по учету рабочего времени

Tags: mysql

HELP! Есть таблица с двумя столбцами:
datetime (дата и время срабатывания датчика),
counter (код сработавшего датчика).
Требуется посчитать количество срабатываний каждого датчика за ночную смену с 20.00 первого дня до 8.00 утра следующего дня.
Дневную смену считаю так:

MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) as date, counter, COUNT(counter) as count  
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(datetime)>='2020-03-20' and (TIME(datetime)>'08:00:00' and TIME(datetime)<'20:00:00') 
GROUP BY counter, DATE(datetime) 
ORDER BY date, counter;
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я бы текущее условие написал бы как `datetime >= '2020-03-20 08:00' and datetime <= '2020-03-20 08:00' + interval 12 hour` Если в условии всего лишь заменить время на 20 часов - получите ночную смену

Comment: Всё гениальное просто! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без работы с датами в виде строк и без привязки к конкретному дню.

```
SELECT 
  DATE(datetime) as date, 
  counter, 
  COUNT(counter) as count  
FROM table 
WHERE HOUR(datetime + INTERVAL 12 HOUR) BETWEEN 8 AND 20
GROUP BY counter, DATE(datetime) 
ORDER BY date, counter;
```

Сдвинул смену в один день (+12 часов), чтобы использовать `BETWEEN`

Пример: статистика за прошедшую неделю от текущего дня

```
SELECT 
  DATE(datetime) as date, 
  counter, 
  COUNT(counter) as count  
FROM table 
WHERE datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
AND   HOUR(datetime + INTERVAL 12 HOUR) BETWEEN 8 AND 20
GROUP BY counter, DATE(datetime) 
ORDER BY date, counter;
```

Comment: Дата мне нужна, чтобы сделать статистику за неделю допустим. Спасибо!

Comment: Дата осталась это общий запрос. Можно подставить в условие с любой даты `DATE(datetime)>='2020-03-20'`

Comment: Ругается на синтаксис, с датой или без даты. У меня Google Cloud SQL.  Цитата ошибки: Error with SQL statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEETWEEN 8 AND 20 GROUP BY counter, DATE(datetime) ORDER BY date, counter' at line 1

Comment: Упс. Буква лишняя, надо `between`

Comment: :)) ой. Спасибо!!!! Всё работает!!!

Comment: про галку на ответе не забудьте )